# c# generics Turing-complete?

Tags: c#, c++, templates, template-meta-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is C# 4.0 compile-time turing complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984490/is-c-sharp-4-0-compile-time-turing-complete)

It is well-known that C++ template meta"language" is Turing-complete. I guess, C# (or Java) generics are not (i.e. you cannot write an arbitrary metaprogram using those).

Has anybody proved that yet?

Comment: I'd venture that this would be better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com